# To install library function for the header files with vcpkg

Tags: c

i am not able to install libraries for the headers with vcpkg for c

The following error was obtained when i had been writing up a c program in vs code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cnsct.png)

when checked it was showing to install library for the header.

any help in installing this library using vcpkg would be appreciable.

Comment: Are you able to compile code ?

Comment: no when i debug the code i get the error as in the image @HarshithVA

Comment: You cant directly compile C/C++ code in VScode

Comment: i m not able too i give run and that is wt i end up with @HarshithVA

Comment: have you installed mingw in your pc?

Comment: give me the link @HarshithVA

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you have not installed the compiler properly.
Follow these steps,

1. Download and Install Mingw https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/
2. 'Mingw Installation Manager' will pop up and you need to select 'mingw32-gcc-g++'->Right click -> Mark for Installation
   3.Installation Menu -> Apply changes -> Apply
3. Now you have installed compiler in your PC but you need to VScode to where this compiler is located in your PC.
4. If you have used default settings then your compiler will be located in `C:\MinGW\bin`
5. Copy the path `C:\MinGW\bin` and Go to Advanced System settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables -> New -> paste path `C:\MinGW\bin` -> ok
6. Setup is done now you can run your code in VScode.